# Writing to Event Log: don't see events in Event Log Viewer but do see them from under Visual Studio.Net

Tags: c#, windows-services, event-log

I am creating a Windows Service in VS.NET 2010 / C# that uses the event log component for logging. I created event source, and the service works under the Local System account so no security related-issues should occur.

While I do see my events in the Event Log view in Visual Studio 2010 (Server browser),  I do not see them in the standard Event Log utility in Windows. What's the problem? My code is below. Thank you in advance for help!

```
        public Service()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Photo Processing Service"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "Photo Processing Service", "fexpress");
        }
        fexpressLog.Source = "Photo Processing Service";
        fexpressLog.Log = "fexpress";
        }
```

then...

```
fexpressLog.WriteEntry (...);
```

Comment: did it create the log for you?

Comment: I did it myself with help of another script:

            myEventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();
            myEventLogInstaller.Source = "Photo Processing Service";
            myEventLogInstaller.Log = "fexpress";
            Installers.Add(myEventLogInstaller);

Comment: im having the same issue - windows7 32bit - you can look in the following directory to see if the corresponding .evtx file for your log exists:

    C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs

Answer (score 1):

Are they falling under the "Application and Services Logs -> Photo Processing Service" instead of the "Windows Logs -> Application Log"?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010 it appears under Servername --> Event Log --> fexpress --> Photo Processing Service. This is correct. In Windows Event Log Viewer, the fexpress log is empty. "Windows Logs -> Application Log" contains general start/stop events (those are created automatically).

Comment: Any chance this is a permissions issue? (VS is running as admin, but event viewer is launched with std user perms?)

Comment: Heck, yes! Is there any way to configure event log so I can view those logs when logged in as non-admin?

Comment: ...Nonetheless when I run Event Log as Administrator, still no events were on the fexpress log.

Comment: Ok... my line of reasoning: Do we believe that the logs really are in there, but just not being displayed for some reason (possibly even because we're looking at the wrong place in event viewer?) I do think they're in there. I'd be curious if you can read them via code, as a normal user...

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider having just gone through this myself.

1. If someone else has already created an event source with the same name you want to use but have mapped it to an event log with a different name then all of your events will be going to that event log instead of the intended.  I discovered this quite by accident after a terrible few hours.
2. An event log source / name can be any length but only the first 8 characters matter.  So, if you previously created a source called, for example, "Photo Printing" then the first 8 characters are the same as "Photo Processing Service" and thus, all your error messages will go there instead.